# Rails - template missing (head first rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm following the Head First Rails book, and having lots of trouble with it as it uses Rails 2, not 3. At the moment, I'm going through the part where it gets you to create a system for booking seats on a flight. The flight's show page has a partial for the seats booked, and a form so that you can book a seat.

I cannot for the life of me get the system to work so that when you click 'book seat' the changes immediately appear in the seat list above. Rails keeps complaining that when I click 'book seat' that there is a missing template for seats/update. I'm even using the 'answers code' directly off the head first site and it still isn't working! Please can someone help!!

Problem 1:

Here is the controller code for the seats:

```
def create
  @seat = Seat.new(params[:seat])
  render :update do |page|
    if @seat.save
      page.replace_html 'notice', 'Seat was successfully booked'
    else
      page.replace_html 'notice', 'Sorry - the seat could not be booked'
    end
    page.replace_html 'seats', :partial => 'flights/seat_list',
      :locals => {:seats =>  @seat.flight.seats }
  end
end

# PUT /seats/1
# PUT /seats/1.xml
def update
  @seat = Seat.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    flash[:notice] = 'Seat was successfully updated.'
      format.html { redirect_to(@seat) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @seat.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Problem 2:

When trying to 'ajaxify' the form, the book is telling me to use remote_form_for, which as I understand it, doesn't appear in rails 3. So I have tried using:

```
<h1>New seat</h1>
<% form_for(seat), :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :flight_id %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :baggage %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :baggage %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Create" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

But that gives me an error of

> Showing c:/Ruby193/coconut/app/views/flights/_new_seat.html.erb where line #2 raised:
>
> c:/Ruby193/coconut/app/views/flights/_new_seat.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
>   '); form_for(seat), :remote => true do |f| 
>                      ^
>   c:/Ruby193/coconut/app/views/flights/_new_seat.html.erb:18: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end

I'm banging my head against the wall here, any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the comma in _new_seat.html.erb and add the equal sign

`<%= form_for(seat), :remote => true do |f| %>`

Comment: Unfortunately that is still complaining of an error:  Showing c:/Ruby193/coconut/app/views/flights/_new_seat.html.erb where line #2 raised:

c:/Ruby193/coconut/app/views/flights/_new_seat.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
'); form_for(seat), :remote => true do |f| 
                    ^
c:/Ruby193/coconut/app/views/flights/_new_seat.html.erb:18: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end

Comment: Oh actually that should be only the first line of the view. You have to add all the needed form fields. After that you have to end the block with `<% end %>`. Please follow your book for that.

Comment: Sorry - I only put up part of the code, I will edit the OP to show what I have for the view - I do already have the form fields, but cannot get the form to work. It works fine when I don't use the :remote => true part, but I also still have the problem that when I hit submit, I get the error that the seats/update template is missing. Any ideas?